# Remove Full Battery Alert Tone in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, sound-theme

I somehow activated the "full battery" alert tone in Ubuntu 18.04, now I want to disable it since my battery has gone faulty and it rings often and is loud too.

How can I remove that tone or how can I disable the service that is looking after battery status and sending a alert that battery is full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by Default in Ubuntu 18.04,

`gsettings` for the schema `org.gnome.desktop.sound` and the key `event-sounds` is `true`

```
pratap@i7:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds
true
pratap@i7:~$
```

making the key value to false will stop all the event-sounds..

to stop only the battery-full event-sound..

check the sound theme-name

```
pratap@i7:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.sound theme-name
'ubuntu'
pratap@i7:~$
```

List and find if it has `battery-full` sound file..

```
pratap@i7:~$ ls /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/
bell.ogg               dialog-information.ogg   phone-outgoing-calling.ogg
button-pressed.ogg     dialog-question.ogg      service-login.ogg
button-toggle-off.ogg  dialog-warning.ogg       service-logout.ogg
button-toggle-on.ogg   message-new-instant.ogg  system-ready.ogg
desktop-login.ogg      message.ogg              window-slide.ogg
desktop-logout.ogg     phone-incoming-call.ogg
dialog-error.ogg       phone-outgoing-busy.ogg
pratap@i7:~$
```

Example Sound theme that have `battery-full` sound file..

```
pratap@i7:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound theme-name Smooth
pratap@i7:~$ ls /usr/share/sounds/Smooth/
documentation  index.theme  stereo
pratap@i7:~$ ls /usr/share/sounds/Smooth/stereo
audio-channel-front-center.oga  menu-popdown.oga
audio-channel-front-left.oga    menu-popup.oga
audio-channel-front-right.oga   menu-replace.oga
audio-channel-rear-center.oga   _message-new-email.oga
audio-channel-rear-left.oga     message-new-email.oga
audio-channel-rear-right.oga    message-new-instant.oga
audio-channel-side-left.oga     message-sent-email.oga
audio-channel-side-right.oga    message-sent-instant.oga
audio-volume-change.oga         network-connectivity-error.oga
battery-caution.oga             network-connectivity-established.oga
battery-full.oga                network-connectivity-lost.oga
battery-low.oga                 notebook-tab-changed.oga
button-pressed.oga              phone-incoming-call.oga
button-released.oga             phone-outgoing-busy.oga
button-toggle-off.oga           phone-outgoing-calling.oga
button-toggle-on.oga            power-plug.oga
count-down.oga                  power-unplug-battery-low.oga
__desktop-login.oga             power-unplug.oga
_desktop-login.oga              system-ready.ogg
desktop-login.oga               trash-empty.oga
desktop-logout.oga              window-attention-active.oga
desktop-switch-left.oga         window-attention-inactive.oga
desktop-switch-right.oga        window-close.oga
device-added.oga                window-maximized.oga
device-removed.oga              window-minimized.oga
dialog-error.oga                window-new.oga
dialog-information.oga          window-slide.oga
dialog-question.oga             window-switch.oga
dialog-warning.oga              window-unmaximized.oga
link-pressed.oga                _window-unminimized.oga
pratap@i7:~$
```

Rename the file `battery-full.oga` with below command..

`sudo mv /usr/share/sounds/Smooth/stereo/battery-full.oga /usr/share/sounds/Smooth/stereo/battery-full.oga.bak`

Thats it.. to make a event sound.. it cant find `battery-full.oga` as it has been renamed as `battery-full.oga.bak`